# Gaming on Ubuntu

Tags: games

Ok so I have the 13.10 version and wine 1.6 Just was curious if anyone can help me find out how to run the d2bs Bot for diablo 2 via Wine. any help regarding this matter would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: look for playonlinux, it is easier to configure than wine and search google, other users might have the answer

Answer (score 0):

Software that might help you with that:

1. Crossover
2. Gaming on linux
3. Virtual machine